# Why cant I install mediate package with R 3.6.1?

Tags: r, package

I wanted to add the package "mediation". R Studio therefore asked for the latest Rtools update, which I installed successfully. When I know try to run the `install.packages("mediation")`, this happens:

```
package ‘checkmate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error in install.packages : ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘C:\Users\Carolin\Documents\R\win-library\3.6’ for modifying
Try removing ‘C:\Users\Carolin\Documents\R\win-library\3.6/00LOCK’
```

I already searched this problem intensively on the internet, but the following suggested solutions didnt work for me:

```
install.packages("mediation", INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
```

as well as

```
unlink("C:/Users/Carolin/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK")
```

I would be happy if somebody could help me with it.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the aforementioned ‘C:\Users\Carolin\Documents\R\win-library\3.6/00LOCK’ by directly accessing the folder and manually deleting the file? (If it actually is a file, which I do not know) [Let's hope it is not an essential file for R to work]

Comment: Glad to be helpful! I'm copy-pasting the comment to an answer, as it helped fixing the issue, and might help for anyone who may have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the aforementioned ‘C:\Users\Carolin\Documents\R\win-library\3.6/00LOCK’ by directly accessing the folder and manually deleting the file (If it actually is a file, which I do not know). [Let's hope it is not an essential file for R to work]